# How can I remove $null and whitespace key/value pairs in a [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary] using PowerShell 7?

Tags: arrays, powershell, sorting, hashtable, pscustomobject

There are plenty of examples of removing null and empty/whitespace keys from arrays, hashtables, and PSCustomObjects. I've adapted and merged several functions I found on this site to come up with this:

```
Function Remove-NullAndEmptyProperties {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        # Object from which to remove the null values.
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline,Mandatory,Position=0)]
        $InputObject,
        # Instead of also removing values that are empty strings, include them
        # in the output.
        [Switch]$LeaveEmptyStrings,
        # Additional entries to remove, which are either present in the
        # properties list as an object or as a string representation of the
        # object.
        # I.e. $item.ToString().
        [Object[]]$AlsoRemove = @()
    )

    begin {
        $IsNonRefType = {
            param (
                [AllowNull()]
                $Val
            )
            return (($null -ne $Val) -and (-not($Val.GetType().IsValueType)))
        }
    }

    Process {

        try  {

            $IsValidType = (& $IsNonRefType -Val $InputObject)
            if(-not$IsValidType){
                Write-Error "Input object is an invalid type."
                return
            }

            if($InputObject.GetType().name -eq 'Hashtable'){
                $TmpString = $InputObject | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 15
                $TmpString = $TmpString -replace '"\w+?"\s*:\s*null,?'
                if(!$LeaveEmptyStrings){
                    $TmpString = $TmpString -replace '"\w+?"\s*:\s*"\s+",?'
                }
                $NewHash = $TmpString | ConvertFrom-Json
                $NewHash
            } else {
                # Iterate InputObject in case input was passed as an array
                ForEach ($obj in $InputObject) {
                    $obj | Select-Object -Property (
                        $obj.PSObject.Properties.Name | Where-Object {
                            -not (
                                # If prop is null, remove it
                                $null -eq $obj.$_ -or
                                # If -LeaveEmptyStrings is not specified and the property
                                # is an empty string, remove it
                                (-not $LeaveEmptyStrings.IsPresent -and
                                    [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($obj.$_)) -or
                                # If AlsoRemove contains the property, remove it
                                $AlsoRemove.Contains($obj.$_) -or
                                # If AlsoRemove contains the string representation of
                                # the property, remove it
                                $AlsoRemove.Contains($obj.$_.ToString())
                            )
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            Write-Output "A terminating error occured: $($PSItem.ToString())"
            $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($PSItem)
        }
    }
}
```

These examples work fine:

```
$Hash = @{
    "Key1" = 'Keyboard'
    "Key2" = '  '
    "Key3" = 'Mouse'
    "Key4" = $null
    "Key5" = 'Computer'
}

$Hash | Remove-NullAndEmptyProperties
```

[image]

```
$PSC = [PSCustomObject]@{
    KeyA = "   "
    KeyB = "Windows"
    KeyC = "Applications"
    KeyD = $null
    KeyE = ""
    KeyF = "Documents"
}

$PSC | Remove-NullAndEmptyProperties
```

[image]

But if I try this:

```
$OHash = [ordered]@{
    "Key1" = 'Alpha'
    "Key2" = '  '
    "Key3" = 'Beta'
    "Key4" = $null
    "Key5" = 'Omega'
}

$OHash | Remove-NullAndEmptyProperties
```

I'm greeted with this:

[image]

How can I iterate over an Ordered Dictionary and remove the `$null` and whitespace keys/values?

I'd like this function to be as robust as possible.

Any solutions are greatly welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would handle null or whitespace values in an `OrderedDictionary` is by enumerating the key / value pairs and using [`[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=net-7.0) to skip them:

```bash
$OHash = [ordered]@{
    'Key1' = 'Alpha'
    'Key2' = ''
    'Key3' = 'Beta'
    'Key4' = $null
    'Key5' = 'Omega'
}

# toggle for testing
[Switch] $LeaveEmptyStrings = $true

# can use `-is [System.Collections.IDictionary]` here
# to target any type implementing the interface (i.e.: hashtable)
if ($OHash -is [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]) {
    $newDict = [ordered]@{}
    foreach ($pair in $OHash.GetEnumerator()) {
        if (-not $LeaveEmptyStrings.IsPresent -and [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($pair.Value)) {
            continue
        }
        elseif ($null -eq $pair.Value) {
            continue
        }

        $newDict[$pair.Key] = $pair.Value
    }
    $newDict
}
```

The logic above attempts to create a copy of the input dictionary, it does not attempt to mutate it, however if the keys could have reference values that need to be dereferenced then you will need to serialize it before making the copy. `ConvertTo-Json` and `ConvertFrom-Json` is a good option.

As aside, this logic can also be re-used in the `PSCustomObject` code path with very small variations in the code, you can use an `OrderedDictionary` to construct the new object then cast the `[pscustomobject]` accelerator:

```bash
$PSC = [PSCustomObject]@{
    KeyA = '   '
    KeyB = 'Windows'
    KeyC = 'Applications'
    KeyD = $null
    KeyE = ''
    KeyF = 'Documents'
}

[switch] $LeaveEmptyStrings = $true

if ($PSC -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]) {
    $newObject = [ordered]@{}
    foreach ($property in $PSC.PSObject.Properties) {
        if (-not $LeaveEmptyStrings.IsPresent -and [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($property.Value)) {
            continue
        }
        elseif ($null -eq $property.Value) {
            continue
        }

        $newObject[$property.Name] = $property.Value
    }
    [pscustomobject] $newObject
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from only checking for type names of `HashTable`, when you should also be checking for `OrderedDictionary`. On another note, this can be simplified to passing it a conditional statement to know what it should remove:

```
if ($InputObject -is [System.Collections.IDictionary])
{
    $InputObject.GetEnumerator().Where({ 
        if (-not ($LeaveEmptyStrings.IsPresent -and $_.Value -eq [string]::Empty)) 
        { 
            [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Value)
        }
    }) | ForEach-Object -Process { $InputObject.Remove($_.Key) } -End { $InputObject }
}
```

As a friendly reminder, by default, you cannot modify a collection while it is enumerating so piping to `Where-Object` would render this ineffective. The work around to this is calling on the `.Where()` *instrinsic* method provided by the `PSObject` wrapper.

This is possible using the `.Where()` method since it immediately filters the collection and produces a separate set of results. Because this filtering happens all at once and outside of the pipeline, the collection is not being actively enumerated when subsequent actions (*like modifications*) are performed. This separation allows for the original collection to be safely modified after the filtering step without encountering enumeration errors.

Comment: You could also check if the object is a ```System.Collections.IDictionary``` - that’s the interface that Hashtable and OrderedDictionary implement. I can’t guarantee the exact syntax right now, but something like ```if( $InputObject -is [System.Collections.IDictionary] )``` should work, and opens it up to working with any other types that implement the interface it as well…

Comment: @mclayton, thanks! I will update it to that if that's the case. I just didn't want to chain a bunch of `$InputObject -is [type]` due to that reason.

Comment: @mclayton, updated it and added changes to summary edit. \@SantiagoSquarzon may benefit from this as well.